# How to access same ServletContext object in another servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

I have written demo program for `ServletContext` object, in which I am setting value by using `context.setAttribute(arg1,arg2)`. and I want to access same object in another servlet.
how can I access the value set by context object ,in another servlet.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String name = "Amrut";

    ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();

    context.setAttribute("contextuname", name);

    out.println("Context==>" + context.getAttribute("contextuname"));
}
```

my question is, for accessing this object i have to create `ServletContext` object and by using `context.getAttribute(arg1,arg2)` ,will i get value. or there is another value to do this.

Comment: Only one `ServletContext` is available per application. Its the `ServletConfig` which is different.

Answer (score 1):

As per the Java doc

```
 There is one context per "web application" per Java Virtual Machine.
```

So your Context Object will be available for all the servlets. and the attributes inside context object will also.

```
my question is, for accessing this object i have to create ServletContext object
```

It will return the same context object, it will not create a new object

Answer (score 0):

> my question is, for accessing this object i have to create ServletContext object and by using context.getAttribute(arg1,arg2) ,will i get value. or there is another value to do this.

You will get value by creating `context` object same as above in the another servlet.
According to [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)

> There is one context per "web application" per Java Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

In service(doGet/doPost) method of another servlet in same application, do this

ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();

String uName =  (String)context.getAttribute("contextuname");